# Swizzling CocoaTouch class in Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I use Swift 3.1 in XCode 8.3 and see that warning:

> Method 'initialize()' defines Objective-C class method 'initialize',
>   which is not guaranteed to be invoked by Swift and will be disallowed
>   in future versions

I use [Swizzling CocoaTouch class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562887/how-to-implement-method-swizzling-swift-3-0) and have an issue with that part:

```
extension UIViewController {

    open override class func initialize() {
        // make sure this isn't a subclass
        guard self === UIViewController.self else { return }
        swizzling(self)
    }

    // MARK: - Method Swizzling

    func proj_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.proj_viewWillAppear(animated: animated)

        let viewControllerName = NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
        print("viewWillAppear: \(viewControllerName)")
    } 
 }
```

How to rewrite that part of the code?

```
open override class func initialize()
```

for fix new warning?

I saw that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824541/swift-3-1-deprecates-initialize-how-can-i-achieve-the-same-thing), but I don't understand how to use info in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3.1 deprecates initialize(). How can I achieve the same thing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824541/swift-3-1-deprecates-initialize-how-can-i-achieve-the-same-thing)

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and fix it.

### My Solution

#### 1. Change swizzling() method to public from private

```
public let swizzling: (AnyClass, Selector, Selector) -> () = { forClass, originalSelector, swizzledSelector in
    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, swizzledSelector)
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
}
```

#### 2. Remove initialize() method at `extension UIViewController`

```
//    open override class func initialize() {
//        // make sure this isn't a subclass
//        guard self === UIViewController.self else { return }
//        swizzling(self)
//    }
```

#### 3. Add swizzling() at AppDelegate::didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // some code

    swizzling(UIViewController.self)

    return true
}
```

This is simply/easy solution. (this is not Elegant)

If you want to get more information, please see this:
 [Swift 3.1 deprecates initialize(). How can I achieve the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824541/swift-3-1-deprecates-initialize-how-can-i-achieve-the-same-thing)