# Set default appearance for a UIView subclass without overriding initialize() in Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

I have a subclass of UITextView, which needs to have a specific default appearance. So far, I've been able to achieve this by overriding the initialize() class function, which has been deprecated in Swift 3.1.

```
public class CustomTextView : UITextView {
    override public class func initialize() {
        self.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing pure Swift?

Comment: you can customize your UITextView appearance overriding the didMoveToSuperview method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working around the loss of the class method `initialize` by using a construct like this:

```
class CustomTextView : UITextView {
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame:frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        CustomTextView.doInitialize
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        CustomTextView.doInitialize
    }
    static let doInitialize : Void = {
        CustomTextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
    }()
}
```

This construct has the advantage that `doInitialize` will be initialized only once, so the code connected with it will run only once (in this case we'll configure the appearance proxy only once); and it is early enough to affect even the first instance created (that is, every CustomTextView you ever make will in fact be green).

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing something similar but I realized that it would require instantiating the class first. So, if you were to configure the custom appearance first, and instantiated the class at a later time, the default appearance would override the custom one. Eg.:

Comment: ` CustomTextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .orange; let t = CustomTextView()`. The background color of t would be .green instead of .orange.

Comment: @DavorBauk Then you asked the wrong question. You don't customize an _individual_ object by setting its `appearance` proxy. You customize an individual object by customizing that object. If that was really your goal, Leo Dabus' answer was right.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You're right, my question wasn't about trying to modify an individual instance; that was really just a simple illustration. In my particular scenario, `CustomTextField` is defined in a shared framework, which is used by several apps. However, each app has a slightly different color palette, so I would want to further customize the appearance of `CustomTextField` in each individual app. For example, have a different default outline color in each app respectively, but keep the default font and background color as defined by `CustomTextView`.

Comment: Okay, but your question was not about that! Your question was about doing something that would behave like `initialize` and that's what my answer responded to.

Comment: Again, thank you for the response. But your solution does not behave like `initialize()`. The documentation states: "The runtime sends initialize() to each class in a program just before the class, or any class that inherits from it, is sent its first message from within the program.". This means that any call to a class method is guaranteed to execute _after_ `initialize()`. Your solution suggests that a user should make sure to first create an instance of the class, discard that instance, and _then_ call the class function such as `appearance()`.

Comment: Well, if you _really_ want the exact timing of `initialize`, you need to override and implement `initialize` in Objective-C, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42824542/341994

Comment: Looks interesting. Working from their solution, I would make my text view class conform to a protocol (eg. `ClassInitializing`) which requires that the class implements `class func initializeClass()`, then on app launch list all classes and for each returned class call `(type as? ClassInitializing)?.initializeClass()`. Is there a way to just check whether a class implements `classInitializing()` and call it using objc runtime functions?