# How to swizzle viewDidLoad method in UIViewController in swift 4? initialize() is deprecated in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4, swizzling

I want to swizzle `viewDidLoad` in a `UIViewController` extension but `initialize()` method which was overridden in `swift3` and was working is not supported by `swift4`. Can anyone give me any solution to this? My code in `swift3` was as below.

```
    extension UIViewController {

    open override class func initialize() {

        guard self === UIViewController.self else { return }
        swizzling(self)
    }

    // MARK: - Method Swizzling

    func nsh_viewDidLoad() {
        self.nsh_viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
    }
```

and have a global method

```
private let swizzling: (UIViewController.Type) -> () = { viewController in

    let originalSelector = #selector(viewController.viewDidLoad)
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(viewController.nsh_viewDidLoad)

    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewController, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewController, swizzledSelector)

    let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(viewController, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

    if didAddMethod {
        class_replaceMethod(viewController, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why would you want to swizzle in the first place? Usually it means you are doing something very wrong...

Comment: Do you understand that what you are trying to do is a very complicated way to do a very simple thing that can be achieved using one subclass? E.g. subclassing `UINavigationController` to hide all back button titles on its controller and then just use your subclass instead of `UINavigationController`?

Comment: I am trying to convert an existing project to swift 4 so if I subclass `UINavigationController`, I need to change in many classes in the project. But thank you for the suggestion this will be my alternate solution if swizzling doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to do it fast, just call that `initialize` from your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Swift 3.1 deprecates initialize(). How can I achieve the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824541/swift-3-1-deprecates-initialize-how-can-i-achieve-the-same-thing).

Comment: @Sulthan Can you please explain how to call `initialize` from `AppDelegate` can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the below code in `AppDelegate` instead if swizzling

```
let barButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
        barButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
        barButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .highlighted)
```